# Installing Ubuntu and WSL2 on a non-Windows drive

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

My 1TB hard disk contains two drive, `C:\ and D:\`, each 490GB. Windows 10 is installed in C:. How can I install WSL2 and Ubuntu distro on D:?

-Thanks

Comment: As this question has been (rightfully) closed as off-topic, I'd recommend posting it over on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) instead, where it would be appropriate. There's a fairly straightforward way to "move" a distribution anywhere you need.

Answer (score 3):

The Distro needs to be stored on your subsystem. You can create a new user.

> [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#troubleshooting-installation)
> [
> The Windows Subsystem for Linux only runs on your system drive (usually this is your C: drive). Make sure that distributions are stored on your system drive:
> Open Settings -> **System --> Storage -> More Storage Settings: Change where new content is saved

### Options to try

These options may work. If not you can always install and set D: as the working directory.

1.**Custom configuration of distro**

[Sample/reference launcher app for WSL distro Microsoft Store packages.](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/)

---

2. **Install via PowerShell and WSL .exe**

Download WSL Distro from Microsoft server to a folder on the D: drive and execute the exe from the command line with config options

1. Open PowerShell
2. Run `Set-Location D:`
3. create a directory for WSL
   `New-Item WSL -Type Directory`
4. Run `Set-Location .\WSL`
5. Run `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing`
6. Run `Add-AppxPackage .\app_name.appx`

[installing Distro -Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#installing-your-distro)